# Mock: Tracking all Calls. Shell vs. program inconsistency

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, mocking, python-mock

Why does the content of mock.mock_calls differ depending on whether I run in shell or 
in a program? The assertion of `mock.mock_calls == expected` fails in a program but passes in the shell.
The code is based on the documentation for tracking multiple calls. [(26.5.1.5. Tracking all Calls)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html#tracking-all-calls)

```
>>> from unittest.mock import MagicMock, call
>>> mock = MagicMock()
>>> mock.method()
<MagicMock name='mock.method()' id='57725952'>
>>> mock.attribute.method(10, x=53)
<MagicMock name='mock.attribute.method()' id='57775944'>
>>> mock.mock_calls
[call.method(), call.attribute.method(10, x=53)]
>>> mock.method_calls
[call.method(), call.attribute.method(10, x=53)]
>>> expected = [call.method(), call.attribute.method(10, x=53)]
>>> expected == mock.mock_calls
True
>>> expected == mock.method_calls
True
```

So far that is all exactly as expected. But look at what happens to `mock.mock_calls` in a program: It records additional calls to the `__str__` method of every method called. mock.method_calls is unaffected.

```
import unittest.mock
mock = unittest.mock.MagicMock()
print(mock.method())
print(mock.attribute.method(10, x=53))
print('\nmock.mock_calls\n', mock.mock_calls)
print('\nmock.method_calls\n', mock.method_calls)

expected = [unittest.mock.call.method(),
            unittest.mock.call.attribute.method(10, x=53)]
print(expected == mock.mock_calls)
print(expected == mock.method_calls)
```

Output:

```
<MagicMock name='mock.method()' id='45740272'>
<MagicMock name='mock.attribute.method()' id='45850128'>

mock.mock_calls
 [call.method(),
 call.method().__str__(),
 call.attribute.method(10, x=53),
 call.attribute.method().__str__()]

mock.method_calls
 [call.method(), call.attribute.method(10, x=53)]
False
True
```

I am running Python 3.4 on a Windows 7 computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are printing the method calls. It causes the [`__str__()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) magic method to be called:

```
print(mock.method())
print(mock.attribute.method(10, x=53))
```

Eliminate the `print()` call and you'll see the desired behavior:

```
mock.method()
mock.attribute.method(10, x=53)
```

FYI, example from the console:

```
>>> mock = unittest.mock.MagicMock()
>>> print(mock.method())
<MagicMock name='mock.method()' id='4433183576'>
>>> print(mock.attribute.method(10, x=53))
<MagicMock name='mock.attribute.method()' id='4433223752'>
>>> mock.mock_calls
[call.method(),
 call.method().__str__(),
 call.attribute.method(10, x=53),
 call.attribute.method().__str__()]
```

---

Or, alternatively, use a normal [`Mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#the-mock-class) class:

```
>>> mock = unittest.mock.Mock()
>>> print(mock.method())
<Mock name='mock.method()' id='4433235528'>
>>> print(mock.attribute.method(10, x=53))
<Mock name='mock.attribute.method()' id='4433252648'>
>>> mock.method_calls
[call.method(), call.attribute.method(10, x=53)]
>>> mock.mock_calls
[call.method(), call.attribute.method(10, x=53)]
```